# Remove classes of word from document

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

Is it possible to remove specific types of words (e.g. articles, nouns, pronouns, adjectives, verbs, adverbs, conjunctions, prepositions, and possessive pronouns) from documents, like how one would remove stopwords from a body of text? If so, how?

I imagine a natural language processing library would have this functionality but I haven't found anything.

Comment: What you are calling "types of words" are called "part of speech tags" or POS tags in the NLP world.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `koRpus::treetag`.

From CRAN:

> This function calls a local installation of TreeTagger[1] to tokenize and POS tag the given text.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to mark the words in sentences with their "Part Of Speech" (POS) using a third-party library and then remove those part of speech tags (e.g., nouns) that you don't want to keep. Examples of these libraries are:

- [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/) - Java
- [CoreNLP](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) - Java and Scala Wrapper
- NLTK - Python

All three libraries use [this list](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) of POS tags, known as the Penn Treebank tag set.

Example of a POS tagged sentence:

**Sentence:** It is possible to remove specific types of words from documents

**POS tagged**: It/PRP is/VBZ possible/JJ to/TO remove/VB specific/JJ types/NNS of/IN words/NNS from/IN documents/NNS